# Problem with QGIS Layer view / Layer Properties view

Tags: qgis

If I open the Layer Properties of my project all is fine.
All styles shown in there stylegroups like shown in the following screenshot sample

[image: QGIS Layer Options - Styles in Groups shown]

But in the Layerview the groups gone. All styles of an layer shown flat in a row. no groups/ subgroups shown.

[[image: QGIS Layerview - Groups are gone - Styles shown flat in a row]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a version issue as I can confirm this works from atleast QGIS 2.8.2-Wien (the earliest version I have):

[image: Layers panel]